# Qt Cancel checkbox check after user disagree on warning

Tags: c++, qt

I have a checkbox which - when checked - will show pop-up warning with information that this may affect on rest of application. For this pop-up user can decide either to proceed or to cancel this operation.

Currently I have a slot connected to stateChanged signal and in this slot I'm checking state and creating QMessageBox accordingly to it. If user will press 'no', I'm setting state of checkbox back to original and return.

This approach will call slot again.
Is there better, more clean way of approaching this problem?

Comment: you can disconnect slot you have connected and then change state of checkbox and then connect it again

Comment: You can also use `blockSignals` to avoid connection/disconnection